# Design for row of list of absences

Tags: android, mobile-application, material-design, listview

I have to create a list of absences, for a mobile application in android, each row has the following data:

- Absence number (Example: N°1, N°2, N°3 ...)
- Date (Example: June 28, March 17, October 9 ...)
- Justified (Example: Yes, No)
- Button (An action button that takes me to a screen to justify the absence)

Which design would be the best (if possible following the guidelines of material design), to represent each row?

Excuse my English, it's not my native language, thank you!

Data:

```
N°  | Date     |   Justified | Action  
=====================================================================
1   | June 28  |   NO        | Action: justify the absence (Button?) 
=====================================================================
2   | June 26  |   YES       | Action: None (already justified)
=====================================================================
3   | June 25  |   NO        | Action: justify the absence (Button?) 
=====================================================================
4   | June 21  |   YES       | Action: None (already justified)
=====================================================================
5   | June 20  |   YES       | Action: None (already justified)
=====================================================================
```

Comment: Hi CristhianS! Have you taken a look at [Material Design's Data Table Guidelines](https://material.io/design/components/data-tables.html)? I think that'd be a good place to start. Have you tried designing this yourself yet? Do you have specific problems you're having trouble solving?

Comment: Thanks for the link, I take into account the guidelines of material design, but on that page there are few examples for mobile, and if I tried to design it by myself but I do not have much knowledge of UX, I am looking for the best way to place the data in the rows, I mainly have doubts on how to locate the action button, I would like to know what is the best way to present the data, also taking into account, for example, that the action button will not always be present as an absence will only be justified once .

Comment: Hi Cristhian, it's hard to say how you should present the data in a data table without knowing what the data looks like and the potential for min/max entries across the fields. For example, you state on a row you could have a number of absences of 3, does that mean in the date column you'd want to display each date of the absence? That's quite a usability challenge to maintain readabiity, especially on mobile. Can you edit your question with more information?

Comment: Hi, you are right, maybe I am expressing badly, the "absence number" is only an identifier, it is not the number of absences, anyway I edit my question, thank you.

Comment: Your sketch seems fine. What about it do you find problematic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Justified and Action as well as the actual Justification can all live in the same column. Such as:

[image]

1. No need to mark if you have or don’t have justification with YES/NO. Rows with justification note are rows with justification, rows with empty justification are rows with no justification.
2. No need to require the user for an “action”. Simply leave the option to edit the justification open for them to make at their convenience.
3. Allow the parent to ADD a justification when empty, and VIEW when already entered. In the screen they enter their justification, you will need to ask for a confirmation once they save their input, telling them the justification cannot be changed. The other way to do this is allowing them to edit whenever necessary since UX should be forgiving to the user to account for mistakes.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the detailed answer, I understand, but how could I solve the fact that justifications can only be sent once, without the possibility of editing them?

Comment: Is there any value to the user seeing what they wrote and sent? Will they ever want to come back to reference what they wrote? Describe me the use case in a little bit more detail. Who is using the tool, for what cases, what do they need the tool for and how it fits into their workflow.

Comment: Well, it is a mobile application for parents of students in a school, in this section parents can see a history of absences and add a justification if necessary, which contains text and attachments, the justification is sent only once without option to edit them.

Comment: Alright, updated my response. I would suggest allowing them to edit so the UX is forgiving to the user.